# Can applications hosted in IIS Express utilize SQL Server aliases?

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-express

I have a Web-API project that is configured with a connection string which sets the Data Source to an alias defined in SQL Server Configuration Manager.  The server runs fine when launched through Visual Studio 2013, but when launched as a separate process using %PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe it fails to connect and eventually times out with the error:

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found

The process works as expected if the connection string is modified to specify the actual server (e.g. localhost) rather than using the alias.

I discovered [this](https://forums.red-gate.com/viewtopic.php?f=167&t=77887) question asked on a RedGate forum which seems to indicate that at least one other person has had this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue of the alias not getting picked up ended up being a result of the 64-bit version of IIS Express running a process that tries to connect to a 32-bit install of SQL Server 2008.  Once I changed the execution path to %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe then it worked correctly.